# Can I use attributes and ModelState.AddModelError both to validate model property in asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, validation

In my asp.net mvc 3 project I use [Required] attributes on properties that need to be validated. Also I use ModelState.AddModelError to add errors to the same properties (with attributes). The errors added with the second approach doesn't show up. What could be the reason?

Here is the code:

1) property with attibute

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Product name is required")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
```

2) in controller action method

```
if (p.Name.Length < 3)
   ModelState.AddModelError("Name",
      "Product name should be at least 3 characters long");
```

3) in the view

```
@Html.EditorFor(i => i.CurrentItem.Product.Name)
        Html.ValidationMessageFor(i => i.CurrentItem.Product.Name)
        @Html.ValidationMessage("Name")
```

So, mabby I can't use attributes and ModelState both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the same thing by adding a `StringLength` attribute:

```
[StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 3)]
```

Where `100` is the max length and `3` the minimum length.

Comment: thanks! great answer! and also more concise way to handle this issue

Answer (score 1):

As for why your implementation isn't working, it is because the first parameter of the AddModelError should be the fully qualified path to your property based on the type the View is strongly typed to. In your case, I believe it would be "CurrentItem.Product.Name"

I recommend using the Fluent Validation library. It allows you to write the custom validation and handles the adding to ModelState for you. It's very nice.

Fluent Validation: http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/